# After Showing Form, Select/Activate Excel Window

Tags: excel, vba

I created a TreeView on a Form that accompanies an excel worksheet.

[image: picture of treeview]

When the TreeViewForm.show is executed, the TreeView Form is selected.  I then need to manually click on the excel window to allow scrolling through the worksheet.  I need to eliminate this manual click by activating the Excel Window.

I've tried a few things

```
TreeViewForm.Show

AppActivate ("Excel")
Windows("TreeView.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets(SheetSelected).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Select
```

I can select cells in the worksheet; however, the Excel window isn't on-top, or highlighted.  The TreeViewForm is.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: VBA <> VB.Net... can you fix your tags?

Comment: `I can select cells in the worksheet;` How? You should not be able to. You are showing the form in `Modal` mode. You will be able to select and scroll the worksheet only if you show the form in `Modeless` for example `TreeViewForm.Show vbModeless`

Comment: From your code and the form design, it looks like you are doing this in VBA?

Comment: I have modal set to 'false' in the VBA editor Form Properties

Comment: even if I change to "treeviewform.show vbmodeless" the form is "selected", so i have to manually click on the excel window with my mouse